# Codeigniter 3 Insert query fail

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mariadb, codeigniter-3

my problem is so weird.
i am trying to insert a row in mysql table (using InnoDB). there are no errors. everything looks fine. but the row is not added into table.

**UPDATE:**

Changing table Engine from **InnoDB** to **MyISAM** will fix the problem, but why InnoDB won't work ?

here is my code and it always returns true:

```
  $this->db->trans_start();
  $this->db->set('userId', '27193');
  $this->db->set('listId', '14');
  $this->db->set('createDate', '2017-02-23');
  $this->db->set('alertReq', '1');
  $this->db->insert('parking');
  if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1') {
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    return true;

  } else {
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    return false;
  }
```

i also tried the insert query in different ways:

```
$parkings = array (
    'userId' => '27193',
    'listId' => '14',
    'createDate' => '2017-02-23',
    'alertReq' => '1'
  );
  $this->db->trans_start();
  $this->db->insert('parking', $parkings);
  if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1') {
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    return true;
  } else {
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    return false;
  }
```

OR

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `parking` (`userId`, `listId`, `createDate`, `alertReq`) VALUES ('27193', '14', '2017-02-23', '1')";
  $query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

when using

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

in my controller, all of the above queries generate and show:

```
INSERT INTO `parking` (`userId`, `listId`, `createDate`, `alertReq`) VALUES ('27193', '14', '2017-02-23', '1')
```

in profiler & even in parking table, the id column will auto-increment by 1.
but there are no new rows added in table!!!

when i use phpmyadmin or adminer to insert that row, they work as expected and i can see the new row is added. but with CI, i have no success!

here is my table structure:

```
   CREATE TABLE `parking` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `listId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `createDate` date NOT NULL,
  `alertReq` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

i tried to delete the *parking* table and recreate it, but no success.
i also tried to create another table with same structure and different name (say *parkingsss*), again no success.

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled in your `config/database.php`

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/transactions.html

Comment: yes. there are no errors. i tried using:
$this->db->trans_begin(); & $this->db->trans_commit(); , but no success

Comment: What is your evidence that "no new rows are added"?

Comment: @RickJames there are no new rows in phpmyadmin & also select query shows nothing.

Comment: You are using codeigniter for writing?  And phpmyadmin for reading?  So, separate connections?  `COMMITting` of transactions becomes critical.

Comment: @RickJames i use codeigniter for both reading & writing. when i saw this problem, for testing purpose i tried inserting and selecting data with phpmyadmin to see the results & as i mentioned, everything works fine when using phpmyadmin or adminer. but with codeigniter, inserting won't add any new records in table when i'm useing InnoDB as table Engine
(changing InnoDB to MyISAM will fix the problem. )
i tried $this->db->trans_begin() & $this->db->trans_commit() as  suggested. but no success

Answer (score 1):

Try trans like https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/transactions.html#running-transactions-manually

Use one db set() like below less lines of code then

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$data = array(
  'userId' => '27193',
  'listId' => '14',
  'createDate' => '2017-02-23',
  'alertReq' =>  '1'
);

$this->db->set($data);
$query = $this->db->insert('parking');

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
   $this->db->trans_rollback();

} else {

   $this->db->trans_commit();
}

return $query; // Returns only true or false;
```

Comment: thank you. i tried your code now. but it didn't work. yet the id auto-increment is adding by 1 , but the row is not added!

Comment: add return false after rollback, then you will see the query fails

Comment: Thank you @Mr.ED you saved my life. Thumbs up